# AS3 hitTestObject different classes

Tags: actionscript-3

How do I get my hit test object to work, the picture is:

One Object in another class should sense when an object from a different class is touching it via hitTestObject.

ActionScript:

```
package  {

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;


public class Grey extends Sprite {
    var blue:Blue = new Blue();
    private var changes:Boolean
    private var directions
    private var speed:int = 20;
    public function Grey() {
        // constructor code
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop)
        /*stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, pressed)*/
    }
    function loop(e:Event){
        movements();
        hitTesting();
    }
    function movements(){
        if (changes==true){
            directions = -1;
        }else{
            directions = 1;
        }
    x+=speed * directions
    }
    function hitTesting(){
        if (this.hitTestObject(blues)){
            changes=true
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just did this a few days ago for a game I'm working on :D

For one thing, you don't have blues declared anywhere. What you want to do is to store all of your Blue objects into an array like so:

```
var blues:Array = new Array();
```

Then whenever you create the array, make sure you put it in:

```
var blue:Blue = new Blue();
blues.push(blue); //yay variable names!
```

Finally, in your EnterFrame function (or hitTesting, since you call that in your on frame function):

```
for each(var blue:Blue in blues){
    if (this.hitTestObject(blue)){
        changes = true; //or whatever functionality. I use a contact function in the object hit
    }
}
```

Edit: One thing to note: your Blue class has NO idea that the grey is touching it. The way you have your code set up, it looks as if grey is aware of blue, but blue doesn't care one way or another. Just wanted to make sure that was clear because of the way you asked the question.

Comment: And, of course, make sure that you actually build these objects and add them to the stage somewhere, or hitTestObject won't work. It works on the rectangular boundaries of the visible objects, so if your Objects here are anything other than rectangles, you *might* need better collision testing if you want it to be pixel perfect

Comment: Thanks I'm about to try this, just to let you know; I have all the objects already in the stage (on the timeline) will this affect what you just told me to do?

Comment: It shouldn't. I don't work with the timeline (I work with straight actionscript in FlashDevelop), but I didn't see them added in your code so I just wanted to make sure. If they aren't added, none of this will work

Comment: is no work :( - I am making pong and I am trying to get the ball (this code is from the ball class) to detect when it hits any of the two paddles and so far it is not working because the ball class doesnt recognise what the blue paddle is, I only have 3 classes for (Ball, paddle 1 and paddle 2) and the stage where everything is already in positioned on. Do you know what I could do?

Comment: Post your full code and I'll take a look. One thing I notice here is that you don't ever change back if you hit the other paddle. You have one place where directions changes to true, but it never seems to get set false anywhere.

Comment: One potential solution is to stop using the direction boolean, and just multiply the speed by -1 directly if it senses a collision. But I don't see your full code, so I don't know if that's the problem. Try adding a trace statement inside your hitTest block to see if it is detecting both paddles. If it is, the problem is probably with the booleans

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'll have to use this last resort, So how do i make this  Ball class sense for collisions without writing code in any other classes?

Comment: Did you add the trace statement? I suspect it already detects collisions correctly, but you're not handling the collisions properly. What was the result?

Comment: It recognises the class, its fine in that sector, but the problem is the hit test object function doesnt recognise the array that I made, (i put the array in the ball class itself) and I get this error `C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\My Actionscript Games (FLASH CC)\Quick and Bored\Pong\Grey.as, Line 32 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Array to an unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject.` But when I take out everything to dow ith hit detection, the ball just flys out of the stage because it doesnt sense anything hitting it

Comment: That is not an error related to your question. Whatever code is on line 32, you are trying to use something as an object (Sprite, probably), but it is actually an array. Try using something like "for each (var name:Object in Array){Do whatever you're doing in line 32}

And it's best practice to have all the objects added to a controller class and have the controller class do the hit testing, btw. You shouldn't really have an array of paddles inside your ball class